# Cakephp delete translation for specific language

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I'm tried to create some translate behaviour on a model. But how do i delete a specific translation.

My example is a Category which has a name that should be translated. Lets say i have a translation in english and spanish. How do i delete the spanish translationsh? offcouse i could create my own sql query but is there a cakephp way to do that.

Comment: No a real delete so the category won't show up on the spanish translated page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There's no cake function to do that

However, it's easy enough to achieve

### Delete all translations for a given locale

To delete all translations for a given locale (As with any destructive action - take a db backup *before* doing anything so you can recover if there's a mistake or it turns out something unexpected is deleted):

```
DELETE FROM i18n WHERE locale = 'esp';
```

Of course, the locale depends on your specific application - you can check your config, or just ask the db:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(locale) FROM i18n;
```

### Delete all translations for a given locale and model

Just add a model condition:

```
DELETE FROM i18n 
WHERE 
    locale = 'esp' AND 
    model = 'Category'
;
```

### Delete all translations for specific model field

You'll need to know the id of the record you want to operate, then:

```
DELETE FROM i18n 
WHERE 
    locale = 'esp' AND 
    model = 'Category' AND 
    foreign_key = 2468789 AND 
    field = 'name'
;
```

If you're not confident directly running queries on the db, run a select first to see what you're going to delete:

```
SELECT * FROM i18n 
WHERE 
    locale = 'esp' AND 
    model = 'Category' AND 
    foreign_key = 2468789 AND 
    field = 'name'
;
```

I.e. find what you want, and then simply change the `SELECT` to a `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help. I just thought there was such function since it so easy to create and edit translations

Answer (score 1):

Suprisingly there is no such native CakePHP method to delete any translations for a given entity. @AD7six is obviously right, but let me give you a more "by-the-book" approach.

You could do sth like this:

```
<a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['action' => 'deleteTranslation', 'foreign_key' => 123, 'model' => 'Pluginname.Controller', 'locale' => 'de_DE']); ?>"><?= __('Remove translation'); ?></a>
```

and then create a method that utilizes that functionality:

```
//put this into src/AppController.php to enable that functionality across the whole application

public function deleteTranslation() {
    $this->loadModel('I18n');
    if($this->I18n->deleteAll([
        'locale' => $this->request->getQuery('locale'),
        'model' => $this->request->getQuery('model'),
        'foreign_key' => $this->request->getQuery('foreign_key')
    ])) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('Successfully deleted a translation.'));
    }
    else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Could not delete a translation.'));
    }
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```